# Check multi permission by middleware

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

I already resolve this problem. I find `Express.js role-based permissions middleware` and use it. It's great and I will re-write my code!

---

I'm want to check multi permistion but it not working for me.

I create 3 middlwares to check Permistion: `requiredAuth`, `checkAdmin` and `checkCompanyManager`.

Model: `User`: {name, permistion, isBlocked, company: {id, userPermistion}}

`requiredAuth` funtion will check and find signedUser, and set it to`res.locals.user`

```
const checkAdmin = (req, res, next) => {
    let user = res.locals.user
    if (user.permission === 2) next()
    else res.json({errors: "Only admin can do this action"})
}

const checkCompanyManager = (req, res, next) => {
    let user = res.locals.user
    let companyId = req.body.companyId ? req.body.companyId : req.query.companyId
    if (user.company.id && user.company.id.equals(companyId)
        && user.company.userPermistion === 1) next()
    else res.json({errors: "Only company member can do this action"})
}
```

And last, I use all in router to check action block user (Only admin or company manager can block user)

```
router.post('/admin/block-by-ids',
    requiredAuth,
    checkAdmin || checkCompanyManager,
    userController.blockByIds
)
```

But it's not working, because if `checkAdmin` wrong, it's break and return json, not run `checkCompanyManager` I can solve this problem as follows:

```
router.post('/admin/block-by-ids',
    requiredAuth,
    (req, res, next) => {
        let user = res.locals.user
        let companyId = req.body.companyId
        if ((user.permission === 2) ||
            (user.company.id && user.company.id.equals(companyId) &&
                user.company.userPermistion === 1)) {
            next()
        } else next("Only admin or company manager can do this action")
    },
    userController.blockByIds
)
```

But it's not fun! I want only use middleware to check and do not want to write code again. How can I do this? I want an idea from you!

Comment: You realize that the `||` operator is defined to return the first truthy value? Since both `checkAdmin` and `checkCompanyManager` are Functions, they are both true and therefore the `||` operator returns `checkAdmin`

Answer (score 4):

The `||` operator does not do what you think it does. It returns the first truthy value:

```
var a = 1 || 2; // a is 1
```

What you need is an **OR** middleware. Something like:

```
function or (middleware1, middleware2) {
    return function (req, res, next) {
        var alreadyCalledNext = false;
        function resolve () {
            if (!alreadyCalledNext) {
                alreadyCalledNext = true;
                next();
            }
        }
        middleware1(req,res,resolve);
        middleware2(req,res,resolve);
    }        
}

router.post('/admin/block-by-ids',
    requiredAuth,
    or(checkAdmin, checkCompanyManager),
    userController.blockByIds
)
```

But the above implementation runs into another problem. Once you've sent `res.json` you cannot send another response. So if either `checkAdmin` or `checkCompanyManager` fails you need to stop them from sending `res.json` unless both fails. So you need to stub `res` and pass a fake `res` (just like what we did with `next` above):

```
function or (middleware1, middleware2) {
    return function (req, res, next) {
        var alreadyCalledNext = false;
        function resolve () {
            if (!alreadyCalledNext) {
                alreadyCalledNext = true;
                next();
            }
        }
        var jsonCount = 0;
        var fakeRes = {
            locals: res.locals,
            json: function (data) {
                jsonCount ++;
                if (jsonCount >= 2) { // both must fail for OR to fail
                    res.json(data);
                }
            }
        }

        middleware1(req,fakeRes,resolve);
        middleware2(req,fakeRes,resolve);
    }        
}
```

This should work.

---

IMHO the solution above feels over-engineered. I would personally make `checkAdmin` and `checkCompanyManager` regular functions returning boolean then wrap them in a `checkPermissions` middleware:

```
const isAdmin = (req,res) => {
    let user = res.locals.user
    return user.permission === 2
}

const isCompanyManager = (req,res) => {
    let user = res.locals.user
    let companyId = req.body.companyId ? req.body.companyId : req.query.companyId
    return user.company.id && user.company.id.equals(companyId) && user.company.userPermistion === 1
}

const checkPermissions = function (checks) {
    return (req, res, next) => {
        // Call next if any check passes:
        for (let i=0; i<checks.length; i++) {
            if (checks[i](req,res)) return next();
        }

        res.json({errors: "You don't have authorization to do this action"})
    }
}

router.post('/admin/block-by-ids',
    requiredAuth,
    checkPermissions([isAdmin, isCompanyManager]),
    userController.blockByIds
)
```

Comment: Note that by the nature of OR logic, you cannot differentiate between error messages for company manager or admin because both must fail for the error to happen (unless you add a checkbox asking if user is admin or manager or somehow develop mind-reading software)

Comment: Thank you very much! I will do it again! You are very nice!

Comment: @NguyenVanTuan - I've modified the code to make it more reusable - this way you can have endpoints that is only accessible by admin or only accessible by company manager

Comment: It's beautiful. your code are reusable easily. Thank you!